# Limit accounts in Google Project using OAuth 2.0 client IDs

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, google-oauth

I am trying to use Google API to develope my first integration service with Google Drive (I am a newbie).
I configuared OAuth 2.0 client IDs as credentials but my service have to limit access only to a specified set of accounts (Gmail).
Is it possible to do this, by setting any parameters in Developer Console?

I can obviously create a login page, but the best solution would be to use something integrated with Google API (preference for PHP).

Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you create a developer account in Google and create an application for Oauth 2.0 , You cant set any limit on email ids(gmail) that can be authenticated by your app in Google.

You will have to do that check in your code. Google doesnt provide that option as far as I know.

Comment: You are correct, Google developer console doesn't limit the number of users that can connect to a project.   That will be up to the developer to limit if need be.